# passing parameter with anchor tag inside mail body

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to passing parameter using anchor tag like the code what is the wrong for this format

````
                   body += "<br /><br />Please click the following link to approve or deny the request ";                      
                   body += "<br /><a href ='http://example.com/test.aspx?approve='"+id+"'>Click here to Approve.</a>";
                   body += "<br /><a href ='http://example.com/test.aspx?deny='"+id+"'>Click here to Deny.</a>";
                   body += "<br /><br />Thanks";```
````

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong?  Are you getting an error?  An unexpected result?  Please describe the problem.

Comment: because the id not exists in the url  after sending the url

Comment: this is the current url  format  `http://example.com/test.aspx?approve=` without the id value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up quotes.  The code appears to be trying to output this:

```
<a href ='http://example.com/test.aspx?approve='123'>
```

Which means the `href` attribute is concluding after "approve=" and the `123'` is errant.  Remove the single-quote before the value:

```
body += "<br /><a href ='http://example.com/test.aspx?approve="+id+"'>Click here to Approve.</a>";
body += "<br /><a href ='http://example.com/test.aspx?deny="+id+"'>Click here to Deny.</a>";
```